# How can I Create a quest menu for my Text-RPG

Tags: python, class

i want to create a quest menu for my text rpg, it should be a list of all quests and after completion the finished quest should be removed fromt the menu. I tried it with a class but i get this error:

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
<**main**.quest_menu object at 0x000001D4F8EC3FD0>

#generate a class for my quest menu

```
       class quest_menu():
             def __init__(self, quests):
             self.quests = quests
```

## generate functions to remove single quests from the menu

```
             def delete_quest_1(self):

             del self.quests[0]

             def delete_quest_2(self):

             del self.quests[1]
```

## generate quests in a list

```
            quests = quest_menu( ["Quest: Murder: kill Rottger = exp: 100, gold 100",
                                  "\nQuest: Ring of strenght: Find the ring of strenght= : exp 50"])
```

## commands to delete quest from inventory when quest is completed

```
            quests.delete_quest_1()
            print(quests)

            quests.delete_quest_2()
            print(quests)
```

What am I doing wrong? Does anybody have some tips to improve the code?
Thx in advance!

Comment: please fix your code indentation

Answer (score 0):

I think what's wrong is that, You deleted a quest first then the only Quest that remains is the second one, this makes that quest first item in the list so using the function to delete the quest will result in IndexError as the quest is now at Index 0. Try to this instead.

```
class quest_menu():
    def __init__(self, quests):
        self.quests = quests
    
    def delete_quest_1(self):
        del self.quests[0]
    def delete_quest_2(self):
        del self.quests[1]

quests = quest_menu( ["Quest: Murder: kill Rottger = exp: 100, gold 100", "\nQuest: Ring of strenght: Find the ring of strenght= : exp 50"])

quests.delete_quest_1()
print(quests.quests)
quests.delete_quest_1()
print(quests.quests)
```

Comment: For the <main.quest_menu object at 0x000001D4F8EC3FD0> part you didnt use quests.quests to print the list you were using the object

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. It seems to work know, but I dont understand the command "quests.quests" to be honest. I guess the first quests before the point relates to my variable quests but why relates quests.quests to the content of my list? Could you explain it in detail?

Comment: Yes Sure, the first quests refers to the object you have created with quests = ... and the quests refers to the attribute quest that is the list of the quests, as if you want to refer an attribute of class through object, the syntax is object.atttibute

Comment: Ah know I got it!

Comment: Thank you Mr. :)